# Dockerfile like alternative

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We all know Dockerfile which is an automated way of building images. Do we have any other options or tools to build images in Docker?

I am not talking about Docker Compose with a build option at any extent, just a alternative tool to Dockerfiles.

I know that we do have cloud based image-builder services, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm a bit vague on what you're searching for, are you searching for a container image "cookbook" alternative or a replacement to docker itself \ its image building binary?

Comment: I mean we use Dockerfile to build images for Docker images. Is there any other way to build Docker images other than Dockerfile.

Comment: Dockerfile is only the format or the rules. the `docker build` binary actually builds the images, if you want another binary other than `docker build` you can use podman or another tool. does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks very much, that’s what I am looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear, please accept the answer so we can close the answer

Comment: was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing it the comments the answer was using another container runtime like podman, cri-o or containerd